# Why telnet and nc command report connection works in azure kubernetes pod while it shouldn't

Tags: azure, kubernetes, networking, azure-aks, telnet

I have an Azure AKS kubernetes cluster. And I created a Pod with Ubuntu container from Ubuntu image and several other Pods from java/.net Dockerfile.

I try to enter to any of the PODs (including the ubuntu one), and execute telnet/nc command in the pod to a remote server/port to validate the remote connection, it's very weird that no matter on which remote server IP and port I choose, they always report connection succeed,  but actually the IP/Port should not work.

Here is the command snapshot I executed:  From the image You will find I'm telneting to 1.1.1.1 with 1111 port number.  I could try any other ip and port number, it always report connection succeed. And I tried to connect to all the other pods in the AKS cluster, they are all the same.  I also tried to re-create the AKS kubernetes cluster by choosing CNI network instead of the default Kubenet network, still the same.  Could anyone help me on this?  Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "any" other IP ? You mean that whatever IP and Port you telnet, it succeeds????

Comment: Yes,  it succeeds for whatever IP and Port.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the root cause of this issue,  it's because I installed Istio as service mesh, and turn out this is the expected behavior by design by referring this link: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/36540

However, although this is by design of Istio, I'm still very interested in how to easily figure out whether a remote ip/port tcp connection works or not in Istio sidecar enabled POD.